# Spring Data JPA and RDBMS and NoSQL

Tags: hibernate, mongodb, spring-data

All,

Is it possible to connect 2 different database (1. RDBMS using Hibernate and 2. MongoDB) using Spring-Data from a single application?

In our application, we would like to deliver images from MongoDB along with the other relational data from MySQL using Hibernate.

I would appreciate all your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

You can have both JPA and Mongo repositories in the same application.

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="your.package.repository.mongo"/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="your.package.repository.jpa" />
```

There's nothing preventing you from using any type of repository combination you'd like.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your response. It works. Now, can I have generic repository for application having NoSQL and MySQL both the DB? Appreciate if can share a sample. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any open source code to share on this topic. I only worked on proprietary code with multi purpose repos.

Comment: You might want to also checkout [spring-data-gremlin](https://github.com/gjrwebber/spring-data-gremlin) which aims to make switching between JPA and any Tinkerpop blueprints nosql database easy.